# C# Cant find file (read from serial port)

Tags: c#, textbox, file.readalllines

I´m trying to open a file named the same as a bar code but I get the error that the file cannot be found?

I use this line to read the file:

```
string[] DxfFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBoxBarCodeScanner.Text);
```

It works fine and open the file correctly if I assign the text box with:

```
textBoxBarCodeScanner.Text = (@"PLANKA.DXF");
```

I use these lines to read from the serial port:

```
RecievedData = RecievedData.Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
textBoxBarCodeScanner.Text = (@RecievedData);
```

I had to remove /r first but it did not help.
I´m kind a beginner so I´m not so good at finding the right debug information for you so here is what I got and please tell me where I found more useful information.
If I break at the exection and look at "locals" I have a row that says text, and there I got "PLANKA.DFX" which seem to be correct.

Debug error message is as follow:

> Additional information: Could not find file E:\Win7\Google
>   Drive\Visual Studio 2013 Projects\Husmaskin GUI\Husmaskin
>   GUI\bin\Debug\PLANKA.DFX.

This works (@"PLANKA.DXF"):
[image: Working textbox]

This does not (@RecievedData)??
[image: Not working textbox]

Comment: So, is the file actually located at the path shown in the error message? If not, where is it located?

Comment: Yes, it is and its the same path as the code executes in, and as it work with just putting textBoxBarCodeScanner.Text = (@"PLANKA.DXF"); in the textbox.
Could it be that it adds something that is not shown?

Comment: Is it possible in some way to get the "raw" string out and compare them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshots, you have two different values for the file extension: `DXF` and `DFX`.

There may be extra whitespace around the incoming text, so I would suggest also adding `.Trim()` to your code.

I would also suggest checking for the file in your code and creating an error message that is more useful to you:

```
var filename = txtFoo.Text;
if (!File.Exists(filename))
     throw new Exception($"Could not find file '{filename}'");
```

Comment: I actually had hard to see the error even when you pointed it out for me.